# Bluetooth stopped working Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth, hardware, reboot

Forgive me if I left anything out

```
    $ dmesg | grep blue
    $
```

`dmesg` returns nothing. I also restarted bluetooth services all threads I've looked at don't work and I have yet to find one specifically for Ubuntu 20.04. This happened after my computer froze up and I had to hard restart it.

Please any help would be greatly appreciated.